# Joing on SQL table with arrays

Tags: sql, presto

I have two SQL tables

TABLE A

---

```
id  |  user | embedding
-----------------------
1      Ram        [.12,.56]
2      Shyam      [.23,.24]
3      Ghanshyam  [.23,.39]
4      Balram     [.34,.39]
```

TABLE B

```
--------------------
id  |  users
--------------------
1      [Ram,Shyam]
2      [Ram,Ghanshyam]
3      [Ram, Balram]
```

And I want to have a query that will return essentially table B but with the users replaced by their embeddings.

Desired output

```
-----------------------------
id  |  users
-----------------------------
1      [[.12,.56],[.23.,.24]]
2      [[.12,.56],[.23,.39]]
3      [[.12,.56], [.34,.39]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: please tag your database as well

Answer (score 0):

how about using unnest and array_agg:

```
select b.id , array_agg(embedding)
from TableB b
cross join unnest(b.users) c(user)
join TableA a
on c.users = a.user
group by b.Id
```